How do I Determine the User when Using Recurly Checkout?
I'm interested in using Checkout from Recurly:
https://docs.recurly.com/docs/checkout
However, I don't know how I would tie a user completing a subscription purchase to a user in my application.
In a different flow (called Hosted Payment Page), I could encode the user ID into the URL, but that doesn't seem to be true with the Checkout flow.

I am having the same issue. It seems rather useless actually becuase there appears to be no way to link our user ID to the recurly account, so i'm not sure what good this checkout page is for anything other than one time purchases.
